# Replace non-NA scores with lm or glm predicted values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a large longitudinal patient dataset. A snapshot of the first 10 columns are displayed below. Briefly, patients fall into different groups (A, B, C) and have been assessed 3 times each. They have undergone many tests, but here I am only displaying the first 4 tests. Test 1 is scored categorically (0 = Fail, 1 = Pass) while Tests 2, 3 and 4 have continuous ranges.

```
ID Group Time Age Severity Func.score Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4
  1     A    1  60        5         50     1   888     5     4
  1     A    2  61        6         45     1     3     4     4
  1     A    3  62        7         40     0     2   888     4
  2     A    1  59        5         50     1     3     6     3
  2     A    2  60        6         40     1     2     5     3
  2     A    3  61        7         35     0     1   999     2
  3     B    1  59        6         40    NA    -4     7     5
  3     B    2  59        7         40     0     3     7     5
  3     B    3  60        8         30     0   888   888     2
  4     B    1  55        7         50   888   999     7     NA
  4     B    2  56        8         NA     0     1     6     3
  4     B    3  57        9         NA     0    NA     6   888
  5     C    1  54        7         40     1     6     5     5
  5     C    2  55        8         40     1     5     5     NA
  5     C    3  56        8         35     1   888     5     3
  6     C    1  60        6         50   888     7     4     4
  6     C    2  61        6         40     1     NA    4   888
  6     C    3  62        7         30   888     5     4   999
```

This dataset has three types of missing values: NAs indicate tests were not administered. 888s and 999s indicate the patient could not do the test because of some physical or cognitive problems.

For each of the 888s and 999s, I wish to replace them with predicted values from a linear regression model (for Tests 2:4) or a logistic regression model (Test 1) using Age, Severity and Func.score, all while grouping patients by their Group and the time they were assessed. I do not want to touch or substitute the other NA values.

My current code is:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
group_by (Group, Time) %>%
mutate(across(8:10, ~replace(., . %in% c(888, 999), predict(lm(.~Age+Severity+Func.score))))) %>%
mutate(Test1 = replace(Test1, Test1 = 888, predict(glm(.~Age+Severity+Func.score, family = "binomial"))))
```

But this code doesn't seem to do the job and produces many errors, such as this:

```
Error in mutate():
! Problem while computing`..1 = across(...).
ℹ The error occurred in group 0: character(0), character(0).
Caused by error in across():
! Can't subset columns past the end.
ℹ Locations 9 and 10 don't exist.
ℹ There are only 8 columns.
```

Can I use `dplyr` or other `tidyverse` packages to do these computations?

Comment: Be careful, you will create inliers and lower your overall variance when imputing by regression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this can be done all within the tidyverse, but this is a case where I find it simpler to just write a `for` loop.  Here's one way to do it.

### Dataset

(For those who don't want to re-type the table given above.)

```
df = data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:6, each = 3),
  Group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 6),
  Time = rep(1:3, times = 6),
  Age = c(60, 61, 62, 59, 60, 61, 59, 59, 60, 55, 56, 57, 54, 55, 56, 60, 61,
          62),
  Severity = c(5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 8, 6, 6, 7),
  Func.score = c(50, 45, 40, 50, 40, 35, 40, 40, 30, 50, NA, NA, 40, 40, 35, 50,
                 40, 30),
  Test1 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA, 0, 0, 888, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 888, 1, 888),
  Test2 = c(888, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, -4, 3, 888, 999, 1, NA, 6, 5, 888, 7, NA, 5),
  Test3 = c(5, 4, 888, 6, 5, 999, 7, 7, 888, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4),
  Test4 = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, NA, 3, 888, 5, NA, 3, 4, 888, 999)
)
```

### Imputing missing values

This code loops over tests, and then over groups.  (It doesn't loop over times; even just dividing by group resulted in model-fitting problems because of the small ns in the sample dataset.  You can add another loop for time with the full dataset - but if you expect similar patterns across groups, maybe just fit a single model for each test, and include `Group` and `Time` as predictors?)

For each test, for each group, it builds a regression (logistic or linear, as appropriate) and fills in the relevant missing values with the predictions from that model.  As a first step towards addressing the concern about inliers mentioned in Yacine's comment, this code adds noise to each prediction: stochastic selection of 0/1 for the logistic regression, and an error term for the linear regression.  Multiple imputation would be a more robust approach; the `mice` package is helpful here.

I've created a new column for each test so that it's easier to compare the old and new columns and ensure the pattern of imputation is correct.  The noise in the predictions is actually hard to see in the output, because the dataset for each model is so small that most of the models couldn't estimate a scale for the residuals at all; this should be better in the full dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

for(tst in paste("Test", 1:4, sep = "")) {

  # Initialize the column of imputed values with the raw values.
  tst.imp = paste(tst, "imp", sep = ".")
  df[,tst.imp] = df[,tst]

  # Build a separate model for each group.
  for(grp in unique(df$Group)) {

    # The dataset for this model includes observations in the group in question,
    # minus any observations with the special 888 and 999 codes.
    temp.df = df %>%
      mutate(test.score = .data[[tst]]) %>%
      filter(Group == grp,
             !(test.score %in% c(888, 999)))

    # Fit a logistic or linear regression, as appropriate, and use the model to
    # generate predictions for the whole dataset.  For the logistic regression,
    # stochastically chose 0 or 1 based on the probability; for the linear
    # regression, add noise to the predictions based on the observed scale of
    # residuals.
    if(tst == "Test1") {
      m = glm(test.score ~ Age + Severity + Func.score + Time,
              data = temp.df, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
      preds = as.numeric(predict(m, newdata = df, type = "response") < runif(nrow(df)))
    } else {
      m = lm(test.score ~ Age + Severity + Func.score + Time,
             data = temp.df)
      preds = predict(m, newdata = df) + rnorm(nrow(df), 0,
                                               coalesce(summary(m)$sigma, 0))
    }

    # Add the predictions to the column of imputed values, but only for the
    # current group and only for columns with the special codes.
    df[,tst.imp] = case_when(df$Group != grp ~ df[,tst.imp],
                             df[,tst.imp] == 888 ~ preds,
                             df[,tst.imp] == 999 ~ preds,
                             T ~ df[,tst.imp])

  }

}
```